# Migrating to other SE sites?

Tags: support, migration, vote-to-close

Is it possible for users with [3000 reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) to vote to migrate a question to another SE site? If not, is it possible for ♦ moderators to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 3k users: **Partially**.

Users are only allowed to vote to migrate to sites that have shown a need for it. In our case, the only site users can vote to migrate to (besides our own meta) is Stack Overflow:

[image: Screenshot of our close dialog]

We haven't migrated enough posts anywhere else to warrant adding migration paths for them, but that can always be reconsidered in the future.

---

For ♦ mods: **Yes**.

On the rare occasion where you do see an off-topic post that belongs on another site, vote to close as off-topic and **flag for mod attention**. Mods can migrate the post to any SE site (including betas). If we start to see a pattern of migrating to the same site frequently, we'll try to get a migration path there so 3k users can handle it directly

Comment: ++ maybe featured tag this question too so people see it. I think they need a different UI though. For now I'd just like migrate to the trilogy sites.

Comment: @xeno If it comes up again I'll feature it. And yeah, I imagine they'll come up with a new way to handle the migration options. I think they're only going to add migration options for somewhat similar sites (so we won't have a migration option for Cooking or Bicycles, since it's unlikely people will post those questions here), and I picture it looking something like [this](http://mrozekma.com/so-mock-se-close.png) (totally made up though, it may be nothing like that)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I think this feature should be available to 3k users, too. Recently I tried to flag a post for being off-topic, but could not specify, which site I think it should be migrated to, because I could only suggest the meta page and SO.

Comment: @polym I don't really control that. There are suggestions on the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for ways to improve it, but they're pretty reluctant to just let everyone migrate wherever they want. The best method for now is to just flag for mod attention and say which site it should be migrated to