# What is the correct way to request that a question be migrated to another stackexchange?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating to other SE sites?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/migrating-to-other-se-sites)

A while back, I posted this question, which did get a couple of answers that just weren't what I was looking for:  [What Windows-related files are valueless to *nix users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/what-windows-related-files-are-valueless-to-nix-users)
Even a bounty only drew a couple of looks but no additional answers.

Could this question be migrated to Superuser?  I think it would do better with the larger userbase there, and I don't want to cross-post it.   I considered flagging it, with a request for it to be migrated, but I wasn't sure that was the right thing, so I didn't.

What is the right way to go about asking for this migration? (or others in the future)