# When flagging a question to be migrated, why are some Stack Exchange sites excluded?

Tags: discussion, migration, flagging

I noticed when I flag a question as off-topic that there is an option to flag the post for migration to another site. However, there is only the option to migrate questions from Unix & Linux to unix.meta.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com.

Some questions asked here would be better served on other sister sites such as Serverfault, Information Security, Superuser, and more.

Is there already an established convention that one should take if they feel a post should be migrated to a site not listed?

If not, this topic has lead me to a couple of points I feel should be discussed:

- Why are these not options to migrate to when you are flagging a post as off-topic?
- Can moderators or us as a community decide what are appropriate sites for posts to be migrated to, or is this left to stack exchange administrators only?

Comment: Because not all paths are opened due to content concerns I guess. All migration paths being open might also end up with users on other sites having to learn the rules of the target site to avoid useless migration and closing effort. Moderators can migrate anywhere (including to and from child metas), but it's not always worth it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why are these not options to migrate to when you are flagging a post as off-topic?

Stack Exchange sites are only allowed so many migration paths, and we have to demonstrate that we regularly have a need to migrate somewhere before they'll add one. See [What is the reasoning behind restricting the number of migration paths?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203318/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-restricting-the-number-of-migration-paths).

> Can moderators or us as a community decide what are appropriate sites for posts to be migrated to, or is this left to stack exchange administrators only?

Ultimately admins control the list of migration paths, but we can certainly request new ones if there's a need. It's come up before ([Can the list of targets for "does not belong here" be expanded?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/971/can-the-list-of-targets-for-does-not-belong-here-be-expanded), [Migrating to other SE sites?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/migrating-to-other-se-sites)), but the only site we've had enough migrations to to warrant adding a path so far is Stack Overflow.

Keep in mind that moderators can migrate anywhere, so if you come across a post that belongs on a site we don't have a path to, you can still flag it, which will get it on the right site plus help demonstrate that we might need a path to that site. In the last 90 days, we've sent:

- 1 post to Ask Ubuntu
- 1 post to Reverse Engineering
- 1 post to Super User
- 1 post to Ask Different