# What is the link to the android site?

Tags: discussion

URL link needed for the Android site for these questions same as Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This site really doesn't need that link. There's the "stack exchange" logo button on the top right. Tapping/clicking on it and entering "Android" will take users to the right place.

It might be worth considering adding explicit migration target sites to the close reasons. Stack Exchange admins are typically a bit shy towards that. I think that's for two reasons:

- we're migrating basically negligible amounts of questions. When you flag a question for attention, mods can still do it manually, no matter whether the target site is listed under "should be migrated to..."
- sending bad questions around to be someone else's problem doubles the overall community effort, with the effect that the target site might still close the question, which then just prolongs the process of telling op to please improve their question, without being specific at all
- migration-initiating voters should be somewhat familiar with the voting rules and spirit of both sites. That's rare enough to come by that it's a fair assumption that most individual votes will not really be qualified
- feeling like the dumping ground for another site's bad question (and be clear here: someone asking a question on the wrong site correlates with not having done enough research) will create inter-community friction that might actually give a bad environment for questions that we migrate manually when we see "oh that's a good question, but that is an Android-specific API that we aren't as familiar with, and we can see that you've done good research"

For previous discussions, see [When flagging a question to be migrated, why are some Stack Exchange sites excluded?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/when-flagging-a-question-to-be-migrated-why-are-some-stack-exchange-sites-exclu)

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer.

It can be found at https://android.stackexchange.com !