# Add new choice for questions belong on different sites in SE

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Currently, there are only 2 choices (Meta and SO), following this flag menu:

> -> A community-specific reason -> This question belongs on another site in the SE

These choices are among the most frequent, but there are more cases where the question fits exactly ServerFault, SuperUser, Math, Softwareengineering, and others, or the same question exists already there (with or without being relative to Unix/Linux).

It would be useful to add more choices. Or one more choice, like "some other site", with the option to specify it (For SO a similar option exists).

Comment: Related: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5435 and similar posts.

Comment: This is a feature request, for a feature already available in SO, to be available for the UL also.

Comment: Still I use "suitable for SO" for questions about hardware stuff or BIOS or other.

Comment: @thanasisp I undeleted this and the other Meta Q you had deleted since they are useful discussions and it's a shame to remove them.

Comment: @terdon I guess there is no shame when you are removing my comments for no reason.

Comment: Sorry, what? Yes, comments can and are regularly deleted without warning, that's normal on all of SE, but there is only one deleted comment on this post and that was deleted by you @thanasisp. If you are referring to my undeletion of this post, I did so because it is useful and I didn't want to lose it. Next time someone has a similar request, we can point them to this post and not need to have the same discussion again.

Comment: @terdon, of course, I don't mean this meta post. I mean useful in-topic comments I had written on a Linux post, and they were removed by the moderators of this place. Also it seems a notice was never sent to a person violating the code of conduct of UL. It's a shame the moderators do nothing for these cases. Also it's a shame you are removing useful technical comments, just to prevent future readers from understanding that someone wrote an answer that doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @thanasisp yes, comments will always be removed without warning. They should either be made edits to the answer/question or removed. There are exceptions, of course, but comments are [ephemeral by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130990/203101). As for whether someone was notified of an infraction or not, I'm afraid that is never public information so I don't see how you would expect to know one way or another. Finally, "useful" is a judgment call. There is a point where the useful technical discussion just becomes a fight and that is no longer useful.

Comment: @terdon, a comment saying "OP asks for the A requirement, so if you use B, you will get an output different than the required one" is not a part of a fight. It is a helpful comment for someone t improve their answer. A part of a fight is a comment containing estimations and opinions for other persons, for their personalities, for their lives, and not for the linux questions.

Comment: For example, if you write to me: "You modify 2 files but the question asks for 1 file" and I answer to you "Don't spam me. You are strange. I 'm not interested." Then **1.** Your comment is not a part of a fight. It should not be removed. **2.** My comment is aggressive. You have to delete it. **3.** Probably I am exactly what I am writing you are, I have no arguments to support my opinion, and I am trying to insult someone and get out. Hopefully my example above is clear.

Comment: I would like to know the reason (in details) for the comments removal (no longer needed?  unfriendly/unkind? something else?) and if this is not for public discussion, I would like to be notified privately. Thank you.

Comment: @thanasisp no reason is ever needed to delete comments, you only need a reason to _keep_ them. I am guessing what comments you are referring to and, frankly, those were not really useful. If you express your disagreement with an answer and the answer's author ignores them, then you downvote and move on. Voting is the way to show issues with an answer, not comments, just voting and, even better, posting your own, more correct answer.